# Android cannot send post

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, post

I am trying to send post to a server from android but it crashes while doing it.
I cannot see if any errors occured, I could not figure out how to monitor http requests in android studio.
Here is my code

```
try {
                String rtoken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                Log.v("tokken", rtoken);
                URL url = new URL("http://my website.com/yyy");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15001);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15001);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("pid",jo.getString("parent_id"));
                conn.setRequestProperty("sid",jo.getString("parent_id"));
                conn.setRequestProperty("token",rtoken);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                writeStream(outputPost);
                outputPost.flush();
                outputPost.close();


            } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and the stack trace of crash 
(JsonParser.java:105) is the line

> OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

[image]

I am really tired of this problem for hours. Any help will be appreciated, thanks,

Comment: Please check if internet connection permission is given or not.Also check below @ManuToMatic answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) about android Thread management. You are trying to do network on the main thread which freeze the UI, that's why you get the "NetworkOnMainThread" exception. 
Try starting a new thread and do the networking there like:

```
(new Thread(){
        @Override public void run(){
            try {
                String rtoken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                Log.v("tokken", rtoken);
                URL url = new URL("http://my website.com/yyy");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15001);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15001);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("pid",jo.getString("parent_id"));
                conn.setRequestProperty("sid",jo.getString("parent_id"));
                conn.setRequestProperty("token",rtoken);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                writeStream(outputPost);
                outputPost.flush();
                outputPost.close();


            } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}).start();
```

Comment: thanks sir, I have learnt a new thing today :) I am so new to Java and android

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to connect to the network on the main thread (ie. MainActivity or another View).

Instead, create an `AsyncTask` and connect to the web from there.